# Ionic 3 doesn't send session cookies on iOS

Tags: php, ionic-framework, httprequest, session-cookies

I have a problem with iOS only, after user login on the next http request Ionic doesn’t send session cookies. My all platform are based on session cookies authentication. When I build android everything works just fine but I have a problems with iOS.

My Ionic info:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.4
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
    ios-sim    : 6.1.2 
    Node       : v8.9.0
    npm        : 5.5.1 
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

### Update

`withCredentials: true` doesn't help, I tried.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Where do you store cookies?

Comment: I don't store anywhere, it has to been received and send automatically.